# magento tier pricing differ for each simple products in a configurable product

Tags: magento

Hi i need to migrate one of my site into magento but i am confused with how the detail page should match exactly same like my old site in magento.

Here is my orginal site detail page [here](http://magnets-web01.inetuhosted.net/Store/Products/personalized-3x4-town-directory-info-magnets-1346)

Here i have quality and i would like to manage this as configurable products in magento. But under each quality products the prices are different and there is an option in magento to add this as tier price. But in magento when i configurable product and add associated products for configurable products i cannot able to see an option to apply the tier prices for the simple products. In magento if a add configurable products and associated products only configurable tier ptice is taking. Do i have an solution for this in magento? If there is any extension please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, got the solution. I have implemented this as set os simple products under grouped products and each simple products i have added the tier pricing.  Check the link [here](http://magnets.zoondia.org/index.php/business-and-card-magnets/2x3-5-custom-business-card-magnets-2x3-5.html)

Comment: The link which you have mentioned is not working. Can you please help by providing any other helpful article?